# Asp.net External Login(google) obtaining all the user details

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, oauth, google-plus

I am trying External Login(Oauth+Owin) in Asp.Net website. I am able to retrieve data such as first name, last name, email, gender etc of a google user during signin. But I am not able to retrieve user's country, telephone number.

Code: Startup.Auth.cs 
This adds all the claims

```
        var googleOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = "************com",
            ClientSecret = "***********",
            Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider()
            {
                OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
                {
                    foreach (var claim in context.User)
                    {
                        var claimType = string.Format("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/{0}", claim.Key);
                        string claimValue = claim.Value.ToString();
                            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(claimType, claimValue, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"));
                    }

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        };
        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleOptions);
```

AccountsController:

```
                if (loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider == "Google")
                {
                    var externalIdentity = AuthenticationManager.GetExternalIdentityAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

                    var emailClaim = externalIdentity.Result.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email);
                    var lastNameClaim = externalIdentity.Result.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Surname);
                    var givenNameClaim = externalIdentity.Result.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.GivenName);
                    var addressClaim = externalIdentity.Result.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.StreetAddress);
                    var countryClaim = externalIdentity.Result.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Country);
                    var stateClaim = externalIdentity.Result.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.StateOrProvince);
                    var postalClaim = externalIdentity.Result.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.PostalCode);
                    var phoneClaim = externalIdentity.Result.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.MobilePhone);

                    var genderClaim = externalIdentity.Result.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Gender);




                    var email = emailClaim.Value;
                    var firstName = givenNameClaim.Value;
                    var lastname = lastNameClaim.Value;
                    var gender = genderClaim.Value;
                    //var phone = phoneClaim.Value;
                }
```

I am able to obtain email, firstname,lastname,gender. But phone number is null as it is not returned.
Is there a way to retrieve the data such as phone number, state, country from google?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'd need to ask for the additional scopes: https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth#login-scopes.  I am not sure,  but I don't think that information is available.

Answer (score 0):

If the user has either not entered a phone number or not added a country then it will not be able to return this data as google doesn't have it.

If you test it it using [Try It](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get#try-it).  With all of the different scopes

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login Know your basic profile
> info and list of people in your circles.
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me Know who you are on Google
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email View your email address
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile View basic
> information about your account

If a user has not set the information in question to **PUBLIC** then you will also not be able to see it.  This is true even if you are checking data for the authenticated user, if its not public you cant see it from the API.